# Extracting a fitting parameter for each element of a For Loop

Tags: fitting, envelope

I have a code that fits a sine wave to small sections of a large data set and uses this to create an envelope function. I am trying to extract one of the fit parameters for each iteration of the For loop using `Reap` and `Sow`. So far I have this code:

```
Rawdata = Flatten[Import["2018050902.xlsx"]];
l1 = Table[l1, {l1, 0, 538}];
Data1 = MapThread[List, {l1/149.44444444, Rawdata}];
Minifit = Reap[For[(i = 1; j = 11), i < 540 && j < 540, (i += 11; j += 11), 
    nlm = Quiet@ NormalNonlinearModelFit[Part[Rawdata, i + 1 ;; j], (a*(Sin[b t + c]))
    + d, {{a, 1}, {b, 0.3}, {c, 8}, {d, -0.5}}, t]]; 
    Sow[Amp = a /. "BestFitParameters"]]][[2, 1]]
l = Table[l, {l, 5.5, 533.5, 11}];
Bigfit = MapThread[List, {l/149.44444444, Minifit}];
Show[ListLinePlot[Data1, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Purple}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"Stage Position (ns)", "Visibility", "55.147mT, No Pulse"}, 
BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Calisto MT", Bold, 20}], 
ListLinePlot[Bigfit, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}]]
envfit = Normal[NonlinearModelFit[Bigfit, s Exp[-a t] (Sin[b t + c])^2 + 
f, {{s, 0.5}, {a, 1}, {b, 1.5}, {c, 8}, {f, 0}}, t]]
PeakPos = Part[l/149.44444444, Flatten[Position[Amp, Max[Part[Amp, 8 ;; 49]]]]];
Peak = Max[Amp]; 
Show[ListLinePlot[Bigfit, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}], 
ListPlot[{Flatten[{{PeakPos, Peak}}]}, PlotMarkers -> {"x", Large}, PlotStyle -> {Black}]]
Show[Plot[envfit, {t, 0, 3.6}, PlotRange -> All,
PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red, Dashed}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"Stage Position (ns)", "Visibility", "55.147mT, No Pulse"}, 
BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Calisto MT", Bold, 20}, 
PlotLegends -> {Style["20A", GrayLevel[0.35], FontFamily -> "Calisto MT", 20, Bold]}]]
```

but there seems to be a problem in the `Sow` command. I want to find the value of the amplitude of the `NonlinearModelFit` (given by the parameter a) from each iteration of the For Loop but I'm not sure how to get it as a list. The command for finding `a` is correct as I can move it to outside the `For` loop and get the final value of `a`. Should I somehow make the output into a table of values of `a` or somehow make `a` into a parameter dependent on `t`?

I'm also looking into how to get error bars for the fitting model mathematica is using. Is there an obvious way to do this?

Comment: does this fix the issue:  replace your `Minifit = ...` with `Minifit = 
 Reap[For[(i = 1; j = 11), i < 540 && j < 540, (i += 11; j += 11), 
    nlm = Quiet@
      NonlinearModelFit[
       Part[Rawdata, i + 1 ;; j], (a*(Sin[b t + c])) + 
        d, {{a, 1}, {b, 0.3}, {c, 8}, {d, -0.5}}, t];
    Sow[a /. nlm["BestFitParameters"]]]][[2, 1]]`?

Comment: an alternative way to get `Minifit` without a `For` loop and `Reap/Sow` is  `Minifit2 = a /. Quiet@
    NonlinearModelFit[
      Part[Rawdata, # ;; # + 9], (a*(Sin[b t + c])) + 
       d, {{a, 1}, {b, 0.3}, {c, 8}, {d, -0.5}}, t][
     "BestFitParameters"] & /@ Range[2, 539, 11]`

Comment: That does work thanks, although I might need to look for a more accurate fit as using the amplitude does not always give an accurate envelope function. Do you know how I could fit the error bars?

Comment: JJH, see [ErrorListPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ErrorBarPlots/ref/ErrorListPlot.html) in the docs and [search results on ErrorListPlot on this site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=ErrorListPlot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing the errors in the relevant part of the code:

```
Rawdata =(*Flatten[Import["2018050902.xlsx"]];*)RandomReal[100, 539];
Minifit = Reap[For[(i = 1; j = 11), i < 540 && j < 540, (i += 11; j += 11), 
  nlm = Quiet@ NonlinearModelFit[Part[Rawdata, i + 1 ;; j], (a*(Sin[b t + c])) + d, 
  {{a, 1}, {b, 0.3}, {c, 8}, {d, -0.5}}, t]; Sow[a /. nlm["BestFitParameters"]]]][[2, 1]]
```

> {14.1488, 18.37, 29.298, -23.3025, 40.3351, -27.7655, -31.2595, 
>       -35.5589, 42612.5, -26.9031, 18.2177, -24.6053, -13.7048, -22346.2, 
>       18.816, -12.9398, -19533.9, 20.0164, -15.1908, 28.9609, -12.5952, 
>       -4532.96, -29.2517, 29.7385, -30.7523, -3519.99, -31.2898, -16.6772, 
>       28.8027, -22.4752, 14.7128, -28.9536, -30.075, 27.8148, -17.35, 
>       29.5031, -21369.8, 48.5057, 3849.14, 26.5289, 17.5288, -13.1019, 
>       -27.8391, 14.5342, 28658.8, -1394.54, -22.5329, 29.4901, -1477.05}

Alternative ways without a `For` loop and `Reap/Sow`:

```
Minifit2 = a /. Quiet @ NonlinearModelFit[Part[Rawdata, # ;; # + 9],
 (a*(Sin[b t + c])) + d, {{a, 1}, {b, 0.3}, {c, 8}, {d, -0.5}}, t]["BestFitParameters"]&/@
   Range[2, 539, 11];
Minifit3 = Table[a /. Quiet@NonlinearModelFit[Part[Rawdata, i ;; i + 9], 
  (a*(Sin[b t + c])) + d, {{a, 1}, {b, 0.3}, {c, 8}, {d, -0.5}}, t][ "BestFitParameters"],
   {i, Range[2, 539, 11]}];
Minifit == Minifit2 == Minifit3
```

> True

Comment: `Table` might be even more suited for this task Instead of mapping over a range of values

Comment: Thank you @Mathe172, good point. I added the `Table` method.